# Multiple signing into pdf using itext 5

Tags: java, itext, signature

```
public List<byte[]> addSign1(List<MultipartFile> files, byte[] img, String[] certificates, SignReq signReq, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, AuthorizationReq authorizationReq) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(files.get(0).getBytes());
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader,outputStream,'0',null ,true);
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = ((X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificates[0].replaceAll("\r\n", "")))));
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    sap.setReason("Hihi");
    sap.setLocation("Hanoi");
    sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(300, 600, 630, 500), 1, null);
    sap.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    ExternalSignature signature = new CustomExternalSignature(httpHeaders,signReq,authorizationReq,signatureServices); 
    MakeSignature.signDetached(sap,digest,signature,new Certificate[]{certificate},null,null,null,0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    List<byte[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(outputStream.toByteArray());
    return result;
}
```

When I sign the first time, and then sign the file for the second time, when I open the pdf file it only shows one signature and is the latest signature, where am I wrong? i want to show more signature into pdf

Comment: At first glance the code looks OK. Merely you should use different coordinates for the signature widget in the second signing pass, but the two signatures should be visible in the signature panel nonetheless. Thus, can you share an example file before signing, after first signing, and after second signing for analysis?

Comment: this file not signing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CvVm-uL09c78y_yWswfw6Dcc3xFvz28x/view?usp=sharing, file first signing :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBOBPIb84XbQyYT8yJSzl1e4qDrYsWgc/view?usp=sharing , and second signing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SAtZVoDYz2jiiHi0xGfw0jiZJo7MJmcl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i change  coordinates but they still show only signature

Comment: The code snippet appears to create a new PdfStamper instance for each signature. If you want to add multiple signatures to the same PDF, you should reuse the same PdfStamper instance for each signature. This way, each signature will be added as a separate signature field in the document and the code snippet sets the visible signature position using the Rectangle(300, 600, 630, 500) parameters. Make sure that you are setting the signature field positions appropriately for each signature. If the rectangles overlap or have the same coordinates, the signatures may appear on top of each other.

Comment: @Sreyas *"The code snippet appears to create a new PdfStamper instance for each signature. If you want to add multiple signatures to the same PDF, you should reuse the same PdfStamper instance for each signature."* - This only is somewhat true if you want _the same, single signature_ to appear multiple times in the document. As I understand the OP, though, they want _multiple signatures_ in the PDF.

Comment: @HoàngTrungKiên Analyzing your example files it looks like the error is not in the code you show but in a PDF processing step executed between signings; in this in-between step the first signature was flattened; it looks like that step was executed in LibreOffice Draw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing your example files it becomes clear that **the output of your first signing ([o.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBOBPIb84XbQyYT8yJSzl1e4qDrYsWgc/view?usp=sharing)) is *not* the input of your second signing**! Some PDF processor processed it in-between and *flattened* the signature field. Thus, the in-document appearance is still there but not the actual digital signature.

Similarly, by the way, your unsigned file ([test.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CvVm-uL09c78y_yWswfw6Dcc3xFvz28x/view?usp=sharing)) is not the input of your first signing, it also has been processed by some PDF processor before getting signed.

If one can take the PDF metadata of your files seriously (which one unfortunately cannot always do), the PDF processor that changed the PDFs before signing each time was LibreOffice 7.5 Draw.

To have multiple PDF signatures, therefore, *do not flatten the PDF after signing* anymore.

Comment: Thank you, what you said helped me fix the error